# Angular & Firebase Firestore - Object is possibly 'Null' Error

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, null, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to get the *uID* ( User ID ) from my auth component in the **app.component.ts** file but it's giving me an **'Object is possibly null' error**.

The function updates/creates a firestore document with the **username & bio**. It gets called only once the user enters the necessary details, but seems like Angular does not know that and thinks that the part of the code that gets the uID is going to be null, and I'm not sure how to go about it. The error underlines the

```ts
this.firebasetsAuth.getAuth().currentUser
```

part of the code. Here's the faulty code.

**app.component.ts faulty code snippet**

```ts
onSaveChangesClick(
  usernameInput: HTMLInputElement,
  bioInput: HTMLTextAreaElement
) {
  let username = usernameInput.value;
  let bio = bioInput.value;
  
  this.firebasetsFirestore.create(
    {
      path: ["Users", this.firebasetsAuth.getAuth().currentUser.uid],
      data: {
        username: username,
        bio: bio
      },
      onComplete: (docId) => {
        alert("Profile Updated!");
      },
      onFail: (err) => {

      }
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a feature of strict typing in Typescript. The currentUser object could be null if no user is signed in. The TS linter has no way of knowing that when this chunk of code gets executed you will have an authenticated user.

You can fix this by ensuring that the user is not null by doing a quick check

```ts
if (isNotNullOrUndefined(this.firebasetsAuth.getAuth().currentUser)) {
  // put code here
}
```

Or by using the optional chaining (`?.`) operator

```ts
this.firebasetsAuth.getAuth().currentUser?.uid
```